# Multicomn with just 2 lines

Tags: multicol

I desire make a template as

IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
 line 1  I line a
 line 2  I line b
 IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
 Another text

The I are just column localization.

I found the multicol package but I have not had success using it.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \hline line 1 line a\\
    \hline line 2 line b\\
\end{multicols}
Another text
```

How I put line a and b to right centralized?

Comment: You don't need [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) for this. You can place the content in a `tabular`. If you provide some more context, in the form of a minimal example (that would include what you actually want as "line 1", "line 2", "line a" and "line b", then it would easy to provide an alternative. Also, what is the alignment requirements for "Another text"?

Comment: I'm at work, so don't have the entire code. I will post later. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example duplicating your output for a much larger portion of text (I defined `\text` to contain some *Lorem Ipsum*-style dummy text).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}

\newcommand{\text}{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.%
}
\begin{document}
\text

\noindent\begin{tabular}{LR}
  \hline
  \text & \text \text \\
  \hline
  \text \text & \text \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\text
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Two column types are created using [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)'s `\newcolumntype`:

- `L`: a `\raggedleft` `p`aragraph column of width exactly `.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep`. This allows for the text to be spread of 50% of the text block while still taking care of the column separation inherent to `tabular`s; and
- `R`: a `\raggedright` `p`aragraph column that mimics `L`.

The `tabular` column separation is removed on the outer edges of both `L` and `R` using `@{}`. Other alignment options are also possible, together with vertical spacing between `tabular` and the rest of the document content.

Note that, since the content is placed inside a `tabular`, it will not break across page boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to flush short lines to the sides and want to input them on a line-by-line basis, you don't require any environment whatsoever, because `\hfill` will suffice.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\begin{document} 
\parbox{5cm}{ \parindent=.5cm % just for show

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\noindent
line 1 \hfill line a\\
line 2 \hfill line b\\
line 3 \hfill line c

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

}
\end{document}
```

To keep the display small I have put everything in a narrow parbox. Here's the output:
[image]